# Athena/iceberg MERGE INTO not applying both DELETE and UPDATE on the same key

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena, apache-iceberg

I want to merge a staging table into main table, the staging table looks like this

```
name | id | keys_id | event_name | event_time
a    | 1  | 1       | INSERT     | 1
b    | 1  | 1       | MODIFY     | 1
     |    | 1       | REMOVE     | 1
```

I have this merge into query:

```
MERGE INTO new_db_test.test_iceberg_table AS target USING new_db_test.staging_table
AS source
ON target.id = source.keys_id
WHEN MATCHED AND source.event_name = 'MODIFY' 
THEN UPDATE SET name = source.name, id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED AND source.event_name = 'REMOVE'
THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND source.event_name = 'INSERT' 
THEN INSERT (id, name) 
VALUES (source.id, source.name)
```

the `test_iceberg_table` should be empty out of this, but the remove event is not applied and the table still has the row with updated value:

```
name | id 
b    | 1
```

When I remove the condition for update, it deletes the record just fine. What could be wrong here? I would also appreciate some resource where I can learn how icerberg applies merge into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each target row is only affected once, and if multiple source rows match then a single arbitrary source row will be chosen. (In some DBMSs you get an error when this happens.)

So you need to pre-aggregate your source, and filter it in some way that `REMOVE` comes first.

```sql
WITH source AS (
    SELECT s.*
    FROM (
        SELECT s.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.keys_id ORDER BY s.event_name DESC) AS rn
        FROM new_db_test.staging_table AS s
    ) s
    WHERE s.rn = 1
)
MERGE INTO new_db_test.test_iceberg_table AS target
USING source
ON target.id = source.keys_id
WHEN MATCHED AND source.event_name = 'MODIFY' 
  THEN UPDATE SET
    name = source.name,
    id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED AND source.event_name = 'REMOVE'
  THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND source.event_name = 'INSERT' 
  THEN INSERT
    (id, name) 
  VALUES
    (source.id, source.name);
```